# XQuery error: Attribute must follow the root element

Tags: xquery, basex

Happy New Year to All!

I am learning XQuery with [BaseX](http://basex.org) and face the following problem now.

I am parsing the [factbook.xml](http://files.basex.org/xml/factbook.xml) file which is the part of the distribution.

The following query runs ok:

```
 for $country in db:open('factbook')//country
 where $country/@population < 1000000 and $country/@population > 500000
 return <country name="{$country/name}" population="{$country/@population}">
 {
   for $city in $country/city
   let $pop := number($city/population)
   order by $pop descending
    return <city  population="{$city/population/text()}"> {$city/name/text()}
    </city>
 }
 </country>
```

but while trying to generate a html running the second query  - if I try to put the `"{$country/@population}"` in the `<h2>Country population: </h2>` tag I see an error message "Attribute must follow the root element".

```
 <html><head><title>Some Countries</title></head><body>
 {
  for $country in db:open('factbook')//country
 let $pop_c := $country/@population
 where $pop_c < 1000000 and $pop_c > 500000
 return
 <p>
 <h1>Country: {$country/name/text()}</h1>
 <h2>Country population: #error comes if I put it here!#</h2>
 {
 for $city in $country/city
 let $pop := number($city/population)
 order by $pop descending
 return ( <h3>City: {$city/name/text()}</h3>,
 <p>City population: {$city/population/text()}</p>
 )
 }
 </p>
 }
 </body></html>
```

Where is my mistake?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using:

```
{$country/@population}
```

copies the *attribute* population in the result.  An attribute should follow immediately an element (or other attributes that follow the element)  -- but this one follows a text node and this causes the error to be raised.

**Use**:

```
<h2>Country population: {string($country/@population)} </h2>
```

Comment: And just a tip: many prefer the more xpath-style `$country/@population/string(.)`. In general this is safer because in the case where the element/attribute value is empty, it will not call the function. If the function were called on the empty value, that could potentially raise an error. It's also easier to read :)

Comment: @wst, Thanks for this suggestion. In fact, the function `string()` allows an empty argument and according to the F&O spec. no error is produced.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Right, but I didn't want to give the OP the idea that most functions worked that way. `string()` is safe, but xpath-style is a good habit anyway, since most functions that aren't.

Comment: @wst, Why do you call this "xpath style" `string(expression)` is at least as much "xpath style" as `expression-selecting-nodes/string()` is. In fact, the former can always be used, while the latter can only be used as the last location step -- it is illegal to have: `'Hello'/string()` but `string('Hello')` is perfectly OK. Also, what you have named "xpath style" is invalid with XPath 1.0 -- where again the "style" I am using is the only allowed. I think that you are seriously misled and also you are misleading the readers by labeling this limited expression style as "xpath style".

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev You've completely missed my point. The advantage is that if `$country/@population` evaluates to empty, and the function *weren't* `string()` and it didn't allow an empty sequence parameter, it would throw an exception. Therefore, `$country/@population/func(.)` is safer than `func($country/@population)`, since the latter is not safe if the expression evaluates to empty. This is why it's good practice. You don't have to call it "xpath style" if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

When you write {$country/@population}, you do not insert the text of the population attribute, but the attribute itself. If you did not had the "Country population text before it", using {$country/@population} would create something like`

If you want its value, use:

```
{data($country/@population)}
```

Or

```
{data($pop_c)}
```

since you have already have it in a variable. (the number or string functions can also be used instead of data, but I think data is the fastest)